# Image processing and capture related features in iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, image-capture

I want to get started on an image processing app. So, I want to understand what support iOS provides for this.
Which is a good place to start and what should I read to get a hang of this topic?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be the [`QuartzCore Framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/_index.html).